# Is "\n" considered one or two characters, and can it be stored in a char?

Tags: c++, string, variables, char

I'm pretty sure the `char` type is for storing a single ASCII character unless any prefix is added. So with this in mind I use the `std::string` type included with `<iostream>` or `<string>`
whenever I need it.

If I store `"\n"` inside a `std::string` and print it, it counts as a single character. Does this mean that I can fit the string in a `char`, even though it appears to consist of two characters?

Comment: "\n" is a character. char[] to represent a string needs "0" to mark the end of the string.  In order to do that, char array requires one more element to store "0" but it is not counted as a string size. So in this case, char array size is 2, string size is 1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The newline character is a single (typically 8-bit) character. It's represented in program source (either in a character literal or in a string literal) by the two-character sequence `\n`.

So `'\n'` is a character constant representing a single character, the newline character.

On the other hand (as [Paul Griffiths' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318930/827263) points out), `"\n"` (with double quotes rather than single quotes) is a *string literal* that represents a *string* value.  That string consists of two characters, a single `'\n'` newline character and a `'\0'` null character that marks the end of the string.

Comment: so since it's a represented as a single character it should work, i just want to make sure. :D

Answer (score 9):

The string `"\n"` is two characters, `'\n'` and `'\0'` - because C-style strings are terminated by a null character, implicit in this case - so no, you cannot fit it into a single `char`. You can obviously store an `'\n'` in a single `char`, but it will remain a single `char`, not a string.

Comment: It may not be clear the OP that when you say `"\n"` is two characters, you're referring to the newline and the implicit null terminator.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I thought spelling out in the answer that those two characters were "`'\n'` and `'\0'`" made it pretty clear, what else would you suggest adding?

Comment: What about in wide strings.. Isn't it stored as `0x00, 0xA`?

Comment: @Brandon: It would be stored in a single wide character, would it not?